# Is there a standard file format for distributing digital comic books?

Tags: file-format

The standard for pirated comic books seems to be a `.cbz`/`.cbr` format, as well as a less frequent `epub`. `.pdf` is being a discouraged (some would say unforgivable) option but not unheard of in the pirate-web-o-sphere.

The question is, is there an industry standard used by official publishers for digital comic books?

Comment: I have been considering using the Marvel ios app lately and paying the $10/mo fee to go back and read those classics. So I should have an answer once I go that route. Great question tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the `.CB*` file format isn't a own file format at all, as it simply represents a standard archive file. That's also where the different endings come from:

- .cbr for Rar files
- .cbz for Zip files
- .cbt for Tar files
- .cb7 for 7z files

and so on...

Those are also the most widely used file formats for comics. But serveral publishers use PDF files along with their security features to sell comic books (as far as I observed, those PDFs are largely disliked by many comic fans)

So to speak for reaching the audience, .cb* should be the best option currently available although it unfortunately isn't a standard fully applied by the industry.